# how to add secuential number getting output with jq

Tags: bash, jq

I'm getting some values with jq command like these:

```
curl xxxxxx | jq -r  '.[] | ["\(.job.Name), \(.atrib.data)"]' | @tsv' | column -t -s ","
```

It gives me:

```
AAAA     PENDING
ZZZ      FAILED BAD
```

What I want is that I get is a first field with a secuencial number (1 ....) like these:

```
1     AAA        PENDING
2     ZZZ        FAILED BAD
......
```

Do you know if it's possible? Thanks!

Comment: Post your JSON with an expected output and not an XY-scenario

Comment: `curl ... | nl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to start your pipeline with:

```
range(0;length) as $i | .[$i]
```

You then can use $i in the remainder of the program.